# friendship: many classes from same parent

Tags: c++

How can I reach `privateMember` without `friend` in all of the derived classes?

```
class parent{...};  //a virtual class

class A: public parent{...};
class B: public parent{...};
class C: public parent{...};
class D: public parent{...};
class E: public parent{...};
...
//each has a function, that want access to privateMember

class MyClass{
    int privateMember;

    friend parent;
    //I know it doesnt't work, but this shows the best what I want   
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leave it as is (with `friend class parent`) and add an accessor function to `parent` that `A`, `B`,... will use. It would be protected, so functions from outside the hierarchy can't use it.

```
class parent {
protected:
  static int& getPrivate( MyClass & c ) { return c.privateMember; }
...
};
```

You have to do this, because friendship doesn't extend to derived classes.

Comment: I have modified the function slightly, to make it match the problem description.

Comment: Ok I got it, I feel it will work.
I thought there is an easier way and I can do that without any setter and getter function. I'm so glad why the C++ doesn't support that by default. 
But that is much better than nothing.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a getter function, that would return a privateMember:

`int getPrivateMember() const { return privateMEmber; }`

This must be a public method of course.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer here is to not go mucking with the internal state of other classes. Instead, use their public API. This way you never have to worry about locking yourself into an implementation AND you avoid a wide variety of potential problems with inadvertently breaking class invariants when you modify the variable.